# generating join condition dynamically in spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to be able to pass the join condition for two data frames as an input string. The idea is to make the join generic enough so that the user could pass on the condition they like.

Here's how I am doing it right now. Although it works, I think its not clean.

```
val testInput =Array("a=b", "c=d")
val condition: Column = testInput.map(x => testMethod(x)).reduce((a,b) => a.and(b))
firstDataFrame.join(secondDataFrame, condition, "fullouter")
```

Here's the testMethod

```
def testMethod(inputString: String): Column = {
  val splitted = inputString.split("=")
  col(splitted.apply(0)) === col(splitted.apply(1))
}
```

Need help in figuring out a better way of taking input to generate the join condition dynamically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure custom method like such would provide too much benefit, but if you must go down that path I would recommend making it cover also `join` on:

1. columns of the same name (which is rather common)
2. inequality condition

Sample code below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def joinDFs(dfL: DataFrame, dfR: DataFrame, conditions: List[String], joinType: String) = {
  val joinConditions = conditions.map( cond => {
      val arr = cond.split("\\s+")
      if (arr.size != 3) throw new Exception("Invalid join conditions!") else
        arr(1) match {
          case "<"  => dfL(arr(0)) <   dfR(arr(2))
          case "<=" => dfL(arr(0)) <=  dfR(arr(2))
          case "="  => dfL(arr(0)) === dfR(arr(2))
          case ">=" => dfL(arr(0)) >=  dfR(arr(2))
          case ">"  => dfL(arr(0)) >   dfR(arr(2))
          case "!=" => dfL(arr(0)) =!= dfR(arr(2))
          case _ => throw new Exception("Invalid join conditions!")
        }
    } ).
    reduce(_ and _)

  dfL.join(dfR, joinConditions, joinType)
}

val dfLeft = Seq(
  (1, "2018-04-01", "p"),
  (1, "2018-04-01", "q"),
  (2, "2018-05-01", "r")
).toDF("id", "date", "value")

val dfRight = Seq(
  (1, "2018-04-15", "x"),
  (2, "2018-04-15", "y")
).toDF("id", "date", "value")

val conditions = List("id = id", "date <= date")

joinDFs(dfLeft, dfRight, conditions, "left_outer").
  show
// +---+----------+-----+----+----------+-----+
// | id|      date|value|  id|      date|value|
// +---+----------+-----+----+----------+-----+
// |  1|2018-04-01|    p|   1|2018-04-15|    x|
// |  1|2018-04-01|    q|   1|2018-04-15|    x|
// |  2|2018-05-01|    r|null|      null| null|
// +---+----------+-----+----+----------+-----+
```

Comment: actually I'm thinking to make it even more generic.. Instead of performing AND between all the conditions, I'm wondering if I could create a tree like structure with a branch for AND, OR queries and the root would be a AND between the branch(AND, OR). What do you think?

Comment: You certainly could.  Keep in mind though in the presence of AND's and OR's, you would have to tell the method how to properly group them.  For example, cond1 OR ((cond2 OR cond3) AND (cond4 OR cond5)) ...  Input of condition rules for the method could get complicated, making the method no longer an intuitive tool.

Comment: cool. just accepted.
do you mind taking a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266116/find-exact-match-and-non-exact-match-between-two-dataframe-spark-scala