# generating join condition dynamically in pyspark

Tags: join, dynamic, pyspark

Can someone suggest a way to pass a listofJoinColumns and a condition to joins in pyspark.

e.g. I need the columns to be joined on to be dynamically taken from a list and also want to pass another condition on the join. Something similar to this done in scala is explained here: [generating join condition dynamically in spark/scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244045/generating-join-condition-dynamically-in-spark-scala)

I am looking for a similar solution in pyspark.

I understand that I can use the join e.g.
a.join(b , listofjoincolumns, how="inner")
but I want to pass a join condition as well:

I want to call it as
a.join(b , listofjoincolumns and join condition, how="inner")

Can someone please suggest a way to do so in pyspark.

Comment: Please provide more information on what you want to achieve. Show the dataframes `a` and `b` and what you want to join.

Comment: df_a = [id1, id2,  date1, date2], df_b = [id1,id2, date1, date2]. I want to join df_a and df_b in a way that I will have a list of the columns to join in as listofcols = [id1, id2] If I did not have the join condition, I could simply do : df_a.join(df_b, listofcols , how="inner"). But I need to pass a join condition as well e.g. joinCond = df_a.date1 < df_b.date2. Now how can I update the join to pass both the listofcols and join condition. Something like: df_a.join(df_b, listofcols, joinCond, how ="inner")

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the list of join columns to a join condition itself:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_
df_a.join(df_b, reduce(and_,
                       [df_a[col] == df_b[col] for col in listofcols],
                       joinCond)
         )
```